# How to create table inside an another table column?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Given a scenario, I have one table lets say Table(Id,name,Question)..I wanted to create another table inside Question Column...Can anybody help me out regarding above mentioned query

Answer (score 7):

Nested tables are not allowed in MySQL.

From your question, it seems that you want to store more than one value corresponding to the question column. You can achieve it by creating a new table say Question and pass the Question ID as a foreign key in your main table i.e. Table

So every row in the main Table "Table" will have a question ID which will refer to a row in the Question Table, in which you can store more than one data corresponding to the Question Entity. This process of breaking the tables to increase flexibility is known as [Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) (though there is much more to the term).

So your tables structure will look like

> **Table**
>
> ID | Name | Question_ID
>
> **Question**
>
> ID | Column1 | Column2 | ......

Comment: Oracle has nested tables - but using a regular 1:n relationship is much better

Answer (score 0):

No nested tables in MySql, but there is a SET datatype that you can use in a table
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html

Comment: But a set has only a limited set of values. I don't see how that could hold an arbitrary number of questions (besides it would not be a good design either).